# Battery Solution for Raspberry Pi 3b

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project for which I need to attach the four raspberry pi boards on the ceiling of the room (one at each corner).

Now, due to the unavailability of power sockets I need some power solutions for my boards. I have 3.7 volt 560 mAH lithium batteries. Is it possible to use these in any way?

Thanks in advance
Aditya

Comment: Please consider asking on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/
It's a community specific for topics related to Raspberry.

StackOverflow is for programming questions and the tag raspberry-pi is only for programming issues related to raspberry

Comment: POE *"Power over Ethernet"* maybe?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and belongs on RaspberryPi Stack Exchange site.